# FirebaseApp not initialized error on changing classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8' to 4.3.9 in build gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

I updated my Android project to 7.0.2 and this changed the

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8' to 
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9'.
```

After the update I started getting an error that FirebaseApp is not initialized or build Gradle does not include gms: google services.

I tried to add

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(mycontext);
```

method also in my Firebase token Async Task where the error is triggering, but this does not help.

Can someone suggest how to fix it?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68688575/8618400.
there is an open issue for this problem https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2894.

Comment: Changing to getApplicationContext also did not help. still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In your app-level Gradle file add the 'apply plugin' line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-bom'
  // If getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have the latest Google 
  // Repository in the Android SDK manager
}

//ADD THIS LINE AT BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

or you can add plugin like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Now, sync both the gradle files

Comment: This is how i had these plugin in my gradle. Does its location matters? buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: add these plugins in app-level build.gradle file

Comment: it is in app-level grade only.

Comment: buildscript { repositories { maven { url 'maven.fabric.io/public' } } dependencies { classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+' } } apply plugin: 'com.android.application' //apply plugin: 'io.fabric' apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  this is in top level gradle file ?